# Using Hostinger to deploy Jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll, web-deployment, web-hosting, web-testing

I'm trying to deploy my Jekyll blog on Hostinger.
It's running fine locally, especially when I used

`Jekyll serve` to run it locally. I then build it using `Jekyll build`  and use FileZilla to push the content of `_site`  to Hostinger, but it doesn't work at all.

My blog is [www.azhir.co.uk](http://www.azhir.co.uk)

Comment: Are you uploading it to the `domains -> azhir.co.uk -> public_html` directory? You might need to zip the contents of your `_site` directory and use their Website Importer if using the file manager didn't work. Failing that you will need to get in touch with Hostinger.